# mix shader node input restrictions?

Tags: 3d-view, shader-nodes

Are there restrictions for what data can be added to a mix shader node?  I am trying to enter two principled BSDF shaders that are connected to a raster image (which is a GIS layer) into a mix shader, but when I try to control the factor nothing changes in my viewport.  Any help would be appreciated thank you.
Attached is a screenshot of my nodes.
[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of your node setup?

Comment: The only restriction is that the inputs have to be outputs from other shader nodes, if you're using Cycles, so that's not your problem.  Are you sure that the output of the Mix shader is going to the Material Output node.  Also, if you're using node wrangler, are you sure that no other node is driving the previewer?

Comment: @RonJensen I added a screenshot of my node setup.  If you don't mind giving my nodes a look that would be appreciated.

Comment: That should work, assuming snow_melt_1.tif and snow_melt_2.tif are actually different images. Like @MartyFouts said, you can use node wrangler to preview the output of individual nodes. Make sure your viewport is set to "Material Preview" or "Rendered." "Solid" won't work even with "Textured" selected.

Comment: As pictured, with fac at 1.0 that should show the output of the lower shader.  The only thing I can see that might be wrong is that somehow the UV map is screwed up, although I can't imagine how.  bug?

Comment: Should be fine.. but _if_ the only difference between your shaders is Base Color, then it would be much more economical to mix the colors, through one shader, then to mix two shaders.

Comment: Robin Betts is suggesting a Color->MixRGB node

Comment: I just got my node network to work because of the suggestion to use the Mix RGB node before my principled shader.  I can not express how grateful I am for the help, thank you all so much!